# Changing the format of a date string

Tags: javascript

I have a date string, `04-11-2010`, in JavaScript I want to have a function that will convert it to `2010-11-04`.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Do you use `Java` or `Javascript`?? They are completely different languages!

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has a string split function, which separates a string into an array of parts.   You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to just chop up the parts of the string:

```
var str = "04-11-2010";

str = str.slice(-4) + "-" + str.slice(3, 5) + "-" + str.slice(0, 2);
alert(str);
//-> "2010-11-04"
```

Another solution is to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on the `-` character, swap the parts around and [rejoin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it.

```
var str = "04-11-2010",
    // Split the string into an array
    arr = str.split("-"),
    // Store the value of the 0th array element
    tmp = arr[0];

// Swap the 0th and 2nd element of the array
arr[0] = arr[2];
arr[2] = tmp;

// Rejoin the array into our string
str = arr.join("-");

alert(str);
//-> 2010-11-04
```

Answer (score 1):

Top of my head:

```
 var dt1   = parseInt(ab.substring(0,2),10);
 var mon1  = parseInt(ab.substring(3,5),10);
 var yr1   = parseInt(ab.substring(6,10),10);
```

Then you have the pieces you need.