# How to convert date into another format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, reactjs

I'm getting a date from an API as

```
 2017-04-20T07:00:00Z
```

How could I format it into the following?

```
 20.04.2017
```

I'm using React to display the date:

```
<div>{props.data.day}</div>
```

I tried for example *toISOString().slice(0, 10);* but couldn't get that to work properly. I also tried looking at other answers, but couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Probably  duplicate of [*Changing the format of a date string*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095677/changing-the-format-of-a-date-string).

Comment: also: have a look at moment.js

Comment: Do you want to use UTC date or convert to local date? Hawaii is UTC-1000 so for them 2017-04-20T07:00:00Z is 19 April 2017 at 9pm (i.e. 2017-04-19T021:00:00UTC-1000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work without any third party libraries:

```
console.log(convertDate(new Date("2017-04-20T07:00:00Z")));

function convertDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    day = day < 10 ? "0" + day : day;
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    month = month < 10 ? "0" + month : month;
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    return day + "." + month + "." + year;
}
```

This gives:

```
20.04.2017
```

You would need to add this to your component as a function and place the return value as the content of your `div`.

Please note, as noted in other answers, you are better off using a third party library that can deal with timezones and other time-based problems without you having to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you store the date as string you can convert it this way:

```
var i ='2017-04-20T07:00:00Z';
var date = i.split('T');
console.log(date[0].split('-').reverse().join('.'))
```

this gives:

```
20.04.2017
```

Comment: This worked well, but I decided to go with another answer. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com) to parse and format the date-string. Choose a library that already does this for you. You should worry about your business logic. Use mature; widely-used libraries to do the heavy lifting for you.

```js
console.log(moment('2017-04-20T07:00:00Z', moment.ISO_8601).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Part of software development is code-reuse. Since you are not developing a date library, you should not worry about creating one.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the result with Regex.

```
function convertDate(date){
    var parsedDate = date.match(/^([\d]{4})-([\d]{2})-([\d]{2})/)
    return parsedDate[2] + '.' + parsedDate[1] + '.' + parsedDate[0]
}
convertDate('2017-04-20T07:00:00Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the day, month and full year to then use as you wish!

```
var oldDate = new Date('2017-04-20T07:00:00Z');

var d = oldDate.getDay().toString();
var m = oldDate.getMonth().toString();
var y = oldDate.getFullYear().toString();

if(d.length < 2){
    d = '0' + d;
}
if(m.length < 2){
    m = '0' + m;
}

var myDate = d + '/' + m + '/' + y;

window.alert(myDate);
```